# How to fix' $ 'modal bootstrap is not defined?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I want to use modal for popup. It is showing me ng ///appmodule/appcomponent host.ngfactory.js sm this page.(which is empty)

**user.html**

```
<div >
    <button data-toggle="modal" mat-raised-button="primary" (click)=display()>Display Student</button>
</div>
<app-display></app-display>
```

**user.ts**

```
declare var $:any;
(<any>$('#modal-display')).modal('show');
```

**display.html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id='modal-display'>
    <p>list works!</p>
</div>
```

It should pop up window of another html. But it is showing me error is '$ is not defined'.and shows this empty page
ng ///appmodule/appcomponent host.ngfactory.js sm

Comment: If you are using **$**, you need to install **jQuery**. But that's not encouraged since you are already using angular material.

Comment: You should never, NEVER **NEVER** use Jquery with angular.

Comment: ok then should i use MatDialog?

Comment: @Minakshi yes there are lot of options are there like Primeng's Dialog, Mat dialog. you can use either.

Comment: or... you could just use bootstrap for angular. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home  Just another option

Answer (score 0):

Probably Issue you are facing because you have not installed `jQuery` package in your application. Run the command to install that -

```
npm i jquery --save
```

PS: It is not advisable/recommended to use **jQuery** with Angular, There are lot of options are there like Primeng's Dialog, Mat dialog, ng-bootstrap Dialog etc you can use either.